# Maven Multiproject Profile activation via property

Tags: maven, properties, profile, pom.xml, activation

I have a problem to activate a profile. There is a master pom with the profile:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>EntityUpdater</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>entityupdater.start</name>
    <value>true</value>
        </property>
</activation>
    ....
```

In my childpom (jar package) I specify the property:

```xml
<properties>
    <!-- ENTITY UPDATER CONFIG -->
    <entityupdater.start>true</entityupdater.start>
    ....
```

But in the build process the profile does not start.

I would be very happy if anyone could help me.

Best regards, Daniel

Comment: Okay.. its not possible at all:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3228

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Maven can only trigger property based profiles, *if* you are passing them in from the command-line as JVM args:

`mvn clean package -Dentityupdater.start`